# How to create a map?

Tags: navigation, mapping, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to define a map for my robot to let it work with amcl, what kind of software you guys actually using to draw map?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/83396/how-to-create-a-map?/) by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2013-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use GIMP IMAGE Editor.

---

Originally posted by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) with karma: 123 on 2013-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use Gmapping package.

http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-09-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-09-26**:
I need it for amcl, which is known map not slam.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2013-09-26**:
I think the known map is created by gmapping or by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use slam_gmapping to create a map of your environment. After that, you can load the created map into a map-server and use AMCL for navigation.

---

Originally posted by [psei](https://answers.ros.org/users/6031/psei/) with karma: 318 on 2013-10-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3